# WiX-Bootstrapper - Set Productname and Companyname for UAC Dialog

Tags: wix, sign, bootstrapper, wix3.7

I have created a Bootstrapper with WiX 3.7.
Now, when I start it on a Windows7 machine, the UAC-Dialog will be shown before installing .NET 4.0 as a prerequisite. Thats ok. I am searching now for a way to "sign" the Installer/Bootstrapper, that I can set the product-name and the company-name for the UAC-Dialog. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are signing tasks built into the wix.targets that will help you sign your Bundle. You can read about the in the [Insignia topic in the WiX topic](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/insignia.htm). The UAC will show the information from the certificate.

Comment: The documentation is incomplete: you'll also want to specify '/t timestamp_url' where timestamp_url depends on where you got your certificate (e.g. http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll for VeriSign/Symantec) - otherwise the signature will be marked as being invalid when the current cert expires.  You'll also probably want to override the 'Program Name' shown in the elevation prompt by adding the '/d' parameter when running signtool.exe - e.g. '/d MyProduct Setup'.